# xunit - how to get HttpContext.User.Identity in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I added a method to my controllers to get the user-id from the JWT token in the `HttpContext`. In my unit tests the `HttpContext` is *null*, so I get an exception.

How can I solve the problem? Is there a way to moq the `HttpContext`?

Here is the method to get the user in my base controller

```
protected string GetUserId()
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
        return claims.ToList()[0].Value;
    }

    return "";
}
```

One of my tests look like this

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestCreateUsergroupItemData))]
public async Task TestPostUsergroupItem(Usergroup usergroup)
{
    // Arrange
    UsergroupController controller = new UsergroupController(context, mapper);

    // Act
    var controllerResult = await controller.Post(usergroup).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Assert
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There really is no need to have to mock the `HttpContext` in this particular case.

Use the `DefaultHttpContext` and set the members necessary to exercise the test to completion

For example

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestCreateUsergroupItemData))]
public async Task TestPostUsergroupItem(Usergroup usergroup) {
    // Arrange

    //...

    var identity = new GenericIdentity("some name", "test");
    var contextUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); //add claims as needed

    //...then set user and other required properties on the httpContext as needed
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() {
        User = contextUser;
    };

    //Controller needs a controller context to access HttpContext
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
        HttpContext = httpContext,
    };
    //assign context to controller
    UsergroupController controller = new UsergroupController(context, mapper) {
        ControllerContext = controllerContext,
    };

    // Act
    var controllerResult = await controller.Post(usergroup).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // Assert
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would suggest you to use `IHttpContextAccessor` to access `HttpContext` and inject via `Dependency Injection` instead of using `HttpContext` directly. You can follow this Microsoft documentation to understand usage and injection of `IHttpContextAccessor`.

With the above code, your code will looks as follows to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
private IHttpContextAccessor  httpContextAccessor;
public class UsergroupController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ...additional parameters)
{
   this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   //...additional assignments
}
```

Once `IHttpContextAccessor` is injected, you can access the Identity as `this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity`

So the `GetUserId` should change as

```
protected string GetUserId()
{
    if (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
        return claims.ToList()[0].Value;
    }

    return "";
}
```

With above change, now you can easily inject the mock of `IHttpContextAccessor` for unit testing. You can use the below code to create the mock:

```
private static ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(
                            new Claim[] { new Claim("MyClaim", "MyClaimValue") },
                            "Basic")
                        );


private static Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> GetHttpContextAccessor()
{
        var httpContextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        httpContextAccessorMock.Setup(h => h.HttpContext.User).Returns(user);
        return httpContextAccessorMock;
}
```

With the above setup, in your test method, you can inject the mock of `IHttpContextAccessor` while instantiating the object of `UsergroupController`.

Comment: The controller already has access to `HttpContext`. `IHttpContextAccessor` was meant to be used outside of a controller.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to the comment by @Nkosi:
there's no requirement to DI the context as you can set it during testing like so:

```
var identity = new GenericIdentity("some name", "test");
var contextUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); 
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
{
    HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { User = contextUser }
};
```