# Mocking HttpContext

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I'm trying to write an Unit Test for my ASP.Net Core application with XUnit framework and MOQ and am trying to test the below method(snippet given below):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Save([FromBody] DTO.ContactUs contactUs)
{
    contactUs.FirstName = _htmlEncoder.Encode(contactUs.FirstName);
    contactUs.LastName = _htmlEncoder.Encode(contactUs.LastName);
    contactUs.EmailAddress = _htmlEncoder.Encode(contactUs.EmailAddress);
    contactUs.Phone = _htmlEncoder.Encode(contactUs.Phone);

    if (HttpContext.User.CurrentClient() != null)
        contactUs.ClientId = HttpContext.User.CurrentClient().ClientId;
    contactUs.UserId = User.GetUserId();
    string dbName = HttpContext.User.CurrentClient().ConnectionString;
    var result = _clientService.AddNewContactUs(contactUs, dbName);

    if (result)
    {
        try
        {
            int clientId = HttpContext.User.CurrentClient().ClientId;
            var clientDetails = _clientService.GetClientDetailsByClientID(clientId);
            // Lines of code...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    return Json(result);
}
```

While I can mock all the other dependent services, I'm kind of stuck with the `HttpContext` part. I am not able to mock the `HttpContext.User.CurrentClient()` part where `HttpContext.User` is of type `ClaimsPrincipal` and `CurrentClient` is an user-defined function, defined as:

```
public static Client CurrentClient(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.Claims.Single(p => p.Type.Equals(AppClaimTypes.CurrentClient)).Value))
    {
        int clientId = Convert.ToInt32(principal.Claims.Single(p => p.Type.Equals(AppClaimTypes.CurrentClient)).Value);
        return principal.GetClients().Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my UnitTest class that I have managed to write till now:

```
public class ContactUsControllerTests
{
    private Mock<IClientService> clientServiceMock;
    private Mock<IWebHostEnvironment> webHostEnvironmentMock;
    private Mock<HtmlEncoder> htmlEncoderObjMock;
    private Mock<IEmailNotification> emailNotificationMock;
    private Mock<HttpContext> mockContext;
    private Mock<HttpRequest> mockRequest;
    private Mock<ClaimsPrincipal> mockClaimsPrincipal;
    private ContactUs contactUsObj = new ContactUs()
    {
        FirstName = "TestFN",
        LastName = "TestLN",
        EmailAddress = "testemail@gmail.com",
        Phone = "4564560000",
        Comments = "This is just a test"
    };
    private ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();

    public ContactUsControllerTests()
    {
        clientServiceMock = new Mock<IClientService>();
        webHostEnvironmentMock = new Mock<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        htmlEncoderObjMock = new Mock<HtmlEncoder>();
        emailNotificationMock = new Mock<IEmailNotification>();
        mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
        mockContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();

        // set-up htmlEncoderMock
        htmlEncoderObjMock.Setup(h => h.Encode(contactUsObj.FirstName)).Returns(contactUsObj.FirstName);
        htmlEncoderObjMock.Setup(h => h.Encode(contactUsObj.LastName)).Returns(contactUsObj.LastName);
        htmlEncoderObjMock.Setup(h => h.Encode(contactUsObj.EmailAddress)).Returns(contactUsObj.EmailAddress);
        htmlEncoderObjMock.Setup(h => h.Encode(contactUsObj.Phone)).Returns(contactUsObj.Phone);
        htmlEncoderObjMock.Setup(h => h.Encode(contactUsObj.Comments)).Returns(contactUsObj.Comments);

        // set-up mockContext
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);
        mockContext.Object.User.CurrentClient().ClientId = 30; // this throws error

        //other initialisations
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void SaveMethodTest()
    {
        ContactUsController contactUsControllerObj = new ContactUsController(clientServiceMock.Object, webHostEnvironmentMock.Object, htmlEncoderObjMock.Object, emailNotificationMock.Object);
        
        // Act
        await contactUsControllerObj.Save(contactUsObj);

        // Arrange
        // Lines of code
    }
}
```

Any help whatsoever on this would very helpful.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951354/5233410

Comment: I can't help but think that the HttpContext won't like being mocked.  [Just kidding]

Comment: @Nkosi I just updated my question and added my Unit Test code in it

Comment: @MissInquisitive No need to mock `HttpContext`. [see link I posted earlier]. Also, use `async Task` instead of `async void` in defining the test mehod.